# Refresh datagrid when changes to database are made

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm writing a wpf application, where I have music albums and corresponding songs. I can add albums and corresponding songs. But now I want to to refresh the view when a change to the database is made. I found many possible solutions, but as I'm new to wpf and c# I don't know which one would suite my code.

In my MainView  have an album list and a add button which opens another window where I can add data with a textbox.

AlbumListViewModel

```
    #region Constants

    IWindowManager addAlbum = new WindowManager();

    IWindowManager addSong = new WindowManager();

    private AlbumViewModel _selectedAlbum;

    private SongViewModel _selectedSong;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public AlbumListViewModel()
    {
        Albums = new ObservableCollection<AlbumViewModel>(GetAlbumList());
        AddAlbumCommand = new RelayCommand(x => AddAlbum());
        AddSongCommand = new RelayCommand(x => AddSong());
    }

    #endregion
    #region Properties

    public ICommand AddAlbumCommand { get; private set; }

    public ICommand AddSongCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<AlbumViewModel> Albums { get; set; }

    public AlbumViewModel SelectedAlbum
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedAlbum;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedAlbum != value)
            {
                _selectedAlbum = value;
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedAlbum");
        }
    }

    public SongViewModel SelectedSong
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedSong;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedSong != value)
            {
                _selectedSong = value;
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedSong");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public List<AlbumViewModel> GetAlbumList()
    {
        var controller = new BandManagerController();
        return controller.GetAlbumList()
            .Select(a => new AlbumViewModel(a))
            .ToList();
    }

    private void AddAlbum()
    {
        addAlbum.ShowDialog(new AlbumViewModel(new AlbumData()));
    }

    private void AddSong()
    {
        addSong.ShowDialog(new SongViewModel(new SongData { AlbumID = SelectedAlbum.AlbumID }));
    }
```

It opens the AlbumView where I add albums to the database.

```
public class AlbumViewModel : Screen
{
    #region Constants

    private AlbumData _data;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public AlbumViewModel(AlbumData data)
    {
        _data = data;
        SongListVM = new SongListViewModel(data.AlbumID);
        SaveAlbumToDatabase = new RelayCommand(x => AlbumToDatabase(data));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public SongListViewModel SongListVM { get; set; }

    public ICommand SaveAlbumToDatabase { get; private set; }

    public string AlbumName
    {
        get
        {
            return _data.AlbumName;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_data.AlbumName != value)
            {
                _data.AlbumName = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("AlbumName");
            }
        }
    }

    public int AlbumID
    {
        get
        {
            return _data.AlbumID;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_data.AlbumID != value)
            {
                _data.AlbumID = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("AlbumID");
            }
        }
    }

    public string AlbumYear
    {
        get
        {
            return _data.AlbumYear;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_data.AlbumYear != value)
            {
                _data.AlbumYear = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("AlbumYear");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public AlbumData AddAlbumEntry(AlbumData albumData)
    {
        var controller = new BandManagerController();
        return controller.AddAlbumEntry(albumData);
    }

    public void ExecuteCancelCommand()
    {
        (GetView() as Window).Close();
    }

    public void AlbumToDatabase(AlbumData data)
    {
        AddAlbumEntry(data);
        ExecuteCancelCommand();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The AddAlbumEntry Method in the ALbumView is in a different class which is the connections to my database. I already use an ObservableCollection but don't know how to tell it the Database was updated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If albums is what the grid knows, then simply add an item to it, or use a method that fetches that collection and call it on init and on data changes to refresh.

Comment: You can use events. Let the`AlbumListViewModel` subscribe to an event of the `AlbumViewModel` which is raised when it modifies the database. Better use a special class to update the database e.g. `DatabaseController`. Then the `AlbumListViewModel` subscribers to its `DatabaseChanged` while the `AlbumViewModel`calls is `AddAlbumEnyry()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to answer my question. I just changed my AddAlbum method to use a Deactivated event, to reload the Collection after the Dialog closes like:

```
private void AddAlbum()
{
    var vm = new AlbumViewModel(new AlbumData());

    vm.Deactivated += (s, e) => GetAlbumList();

    addAlbum.ShowDialog(vm);
}
```